Black screen when running game or some app in lutris with dedicated gpu
I have laptop Lenovo g50-45 with kubuntu installed, with amd R5 igpu and amd m330 dgpu.
I recently installed window game in lutris using wine latest one.
The game runs lagging and when i checked it was using igpu.
I switched to dgpu from system settings but it just shows black screen and doesn't start. Any way to fix it?
